# access file in client side on serverside in vb.net

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [asp.net file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976489/asp-net-file-size)

Hai,

I want to check the file size before uploading to server from client side in vb.net. If it is a zero byte file then user prompt with warning . For that I used

```
Dim fileDetails As IO.FileInfo
fileDetails = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(filePath)
Dim fileSize As Integer = fileDetails.Length  
if fileSize =0 then
   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType(), "3", "<script>ShowMessage('we cannot upload 0bytes file');</script>")
End If
```

all files selected are listed in grid before uploading. When i used the above code it works perfectly on client side but when i tried to run from IIS the files not added to grid. What is the problem with the above code? How can i access the file from client side on server in vb.net